# How to store RDF data to a triplestore in Fuseki SPARQL endpoint using RDFlib in python

Tags: sparql, rdf, fuseki, rdflib, triplestore

New Question:

I firstly start the Fuseki Server to create a new dataset called 'address_act':

```
fuseki-server --update --mem /address_act
```

here are the code to get data of each address and then add it to a Triplestore (database) in Fuseki Server:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
from rdflib import Graph, Literal, URIRef
from rdflib.plugins.stores import sparqlstore

query_endpoint = 'http://localhost:3030/address_act/query'
update_endpoint = 'http://localhost:3030/address_act/update'
store = sparqlstore.SPARQLUpdateStore()
store.open((query_endpoint, update_endpoint))
g = Graph(identifier = URIRef('http://www.example.com'))

for i in range(1,3):
    results = []
    url = 'http://gnafld.net/address/?per_page=10&page=' + str(i)
    page = requests.get(url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
    results = re.findall('\"Address ID: (GAACT[0-9]+)\"', response.text)

    for ad in results:
        ad_url = 'http://gnafld.net/address/' + ad
        ad_info = requests.get(ad_url).content

        g.parse(data=ad_info, format='turtle')
        store.add_graph(g)
```

It seems that the code works but when I browse http://localhost:3030/dataset.html?tab=info&ds=/address_act, It always shows that there is 0 triples in the graph.[no triples in the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o21Bp.png) I wonder whether it inserts the triples into the dataset successfully. If yes, then where can I find those triples? If not, how can I add the triples into the default graph? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: SPARQL 1.1 Update query with `SPARQLUpdateStore`

Comment: I am sorry I am new to stackoverflow and not very familiar with the operations. I have edited the question but have no idea why it said too many values to unpack.

Answer (score 2):

If you start fuseki like this:

```
$ fuseki-server --update --mem /ds
```

Then you can access it locally using:

```
from rdflib import Graph, Literal, URIRef
from rdflib.plugins.stores import sparqlstore

query_endpoint = 'http://localhost:3030/ds/query'
update_endpoint = 'http://localhost:3030/ds/update'
store = sparqlstore.SPARQLUpdateStore()
store.open((query_endpoint, update_endpoint))

...use store...
store.add_graph(graph)
store.remove_graph(graph)
store.query(...)
```

(`ds` is name of the fuseki dataset)

It looks like you have a turtle format file so:

```
g = Graph(identifier = URIRef('http://www.example.com/'))
g.parse(data=r, format='turtle')

store.add_graph(g)
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention and time. I just run the code but got the error above. I have already edited the problem description. Could you plz help me with that? Can you run it without errors?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Then the error is 'SPARQLUpdateStore' object has no attribute 'add_Graph'. Then I change to store.add(g) and it said 'too many values to unpack (expected 3)' as i re-edit above.

Comment: `add_graph` - lowercase 'g'

Comment: update: forgot that rdflib 'graph' is a bit odd and includes an 'identifier'. No idea how to just use the default graph, but updated code works.

Comment: It seems that the code works. But in the Fuseki Server, it always shows that 0 triples in the default graph. Then which graph should the inserted triples should be in?

Comment: http://www.example.com - that's what the graph identifier does. Apologies, couldn't work out how to get it in the default graph (although you could set fuseki to use default union graph).

Comment: I am really confused whether I insert the triples successfully though the code works because there is 0 triple in the endpoint. And I cannot find any result from http://www.example.com....

Comment: Try `select (count(*) AS ?count) { graph <http://www.example.com/> { ?s ?p ?o } }`?

Comment: When I print (len(g)), it shows 22 triples in the graph. But when I try the SPARQL query you mentioned above, it still shows 0 there. Really confused and have no idea why...

Comment: I am sorry I did not get your idea. what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 1):

## Summary

Took me a while to figure this out but finally and by help of [this post](https://groups.google.com/g/rdflib-dev/c/dGUZ1QTlAaM?pli=1), I found a solution:

To load your data into the default graph, you can use the *magic url* for the
default graph provided by rdflib like so:

```py
from rdflib.graph import DATASET_DEFAULT_GRAPH_ID as default
```

You then pass the `default` variable to the graph constructor, e.g.

```
graph = Graph(store, identifier=default)
```

## Complete example

This assumes that apache-jena-fuseki is running on port 3030 on localhost (the default).

```py
from rdflib import Namespace, Graph
from rdflib.namespace import RDF, FOAF
from rdflib.plugins.stores.sparqlstore import SPARQLUpdateStore
from rdflib.graph import DATASET_DEFAULT_GRAPH_ID as default

# Connect to fuseki triplestore.
store = SPARQLUpdateStore()
query_endpoint = 'http://localhost:3030/test/query'
update_endpoint = 'http://localhost:3030/test/update'
store.open((query_endpoint, update_endpoint))

# Define example namespace.
ex = Namespace("http://example.org/")

# Define a node.
node = (ex.me, RDF.type, FOAF.Person)

# Open a graph in the open store and set identifier to default graph ID.
graph = Graph(store, identifier=default)

# Add node to graph.
graph.add(node)
```

You should then see one (new) node in the fuseki dataset admin panel,
[see this screenshot of fuseki dataset info panel after inserting one node into default graph using rdflib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjTc7.png).